# VBA, if a string contains a certain letter

Tags: vba, excel

I do not usually work with `VBA` and I cannot figure this out.  I am trying to determine whether a certain letter is contained within a string on my spreadhseet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myString As String
RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
MsgBox RowCount
For i = 2 To RowCount
    myString = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If myString.Contains("A") Then
        oldStr = Cells(i, 15).Value
        newStr = Left(oldStr, oldStr.IndexOf("A"))
    End If
Next          
End Sub
```

This code should go through a list of values and if it encounters the letter A to remove it and everything that comes after it.  I am getting problems at my `IF` statement, Invalid Qualifier.  How would I be able to make my `IF` statement output whether or not the String in the cell contains the letter A?

Thank you very much

Comment: For those wondering, the error is in this line: newStr = Left(oldStr, oldStr.IndexOf("A"))  Can you tell us in words what that line is supposed to be doing? IndexOf doesn't exist in the object model.

Comment: Are you doing this in VBA?  Your code looks very VB.Net-ish.  Note that string data type does not have **any** methods or properties (sugh as `.Contains` or `.IndexOf`, etc.).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using the InStr function which returns the index in the string at which the character was found. If InStr returns 0, the string was not found.

```
If InStr(myString, "A") > 0 Then
```

[InStr MSDN Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

For the error on the line assigning to newStr, convert oldStr.IndexOf to that InStr function also.

```
Left(oldStr, InStr(oldStr, "A"))
```

Comment: It gave me the error Object required.  I do not understand what is making this so complicated.

Comment: What's making it so complicated is that you are not accurately describing your problems: when you get an error, it is important for you to tell *what line raises the error*. @user1923086

Comment: @user1923086 See my edit for what seems (on my end) to fix the error in your comment on the main post. I don't know that VBA supports the IndexOf function.

Comment: No, it doesn't. OP is using VB.NET constructs in VBA. This will never work :)

Comment: @DavidZemens That's what I thought but I didn't want to say absolutely when only 90% sure. Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
If myString like "*A*" Then
```

Comment: It gave me the error Object required.  I do not understand what is making this so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looping through a lot of cells, use the binary function, it is much faster.
Using "<> 0" in place of "> 0" also makes it faster:

```
If InStrB(1, myString, "a", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0
```

Comment: That works very nicely thank you but it still gives me the error Object Required.  I now believe the error is coming from the following line.

newStr = Left(oldStr, oldStr.IndexOf("A"))

Comment: @user1923086 see my comment above and in Mark Balhoff's answer, below. Your errors are because you're using VB.NET code which is not compaitble with VBA.

Comment: Thanks it's a bit confusing when lookign through the Microsoft MSDN.  It may just be habit now but I sometimes wish they organised it a bit better, simialrly to the Oracle JAVA API.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but it will loop through the range that you gave it and if it finds an "A" it will remove it from the cell.  I'm not sure what oldStr is used for...

```
Private Sub foo()
Dim myString As String
RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To RowCount
    myString = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If InStr(myString, "A") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(myString, InStr(myString, "A"))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked marvellously.  One little correction in order to remove the A:
Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(myString, InStr(myString, "A")-1)

oldString was part of my frankenstein code in an attempt to debug.  Thank you again.