# Excel Macro VBA - Does cell contain instead of exact match

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding in general and need to write a macro. The below code searches for text in a field and if so it takes a quantity from that column and duplicates it in another cell. Then repeats for the entire Row, Which does work, but the text in the cell needs to be exact.

```
Sub Test()

Dim variable As String
variable = "insert value or cell here"

With Sheets("Test")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "N").Value = "Blue" Or .Cells(i, "N").Value = "Red" Or .Cells(i, "N").Value = "Green" Then
            .Cells(i, "AV").Value = .Cells(i, "P").Value
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

With some looking around online I have put together the below code to instead come back positive if the value appears anywhere in that cell, but I cant get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

Dim variable As String
variable = "insert value or cell here"

With Sheets("Test")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If InStr(.Cells(i, "M"), Value = "Red" or Value = "Green" or Value = "Blue") Then
            .Cells(i, "AV").Value = .Cells(i, "P").Value

        Else: .Cells(i, "AV").Value = "0"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `InStr()` accepts one argument for where to look and a second argument for what to find; it outputs long.  you would need to split your `instr()` to have each, OR create a loop or switch to support different values.

Comment: Use the Excel Find command and if it's result is 0 or greater the cell or string contains your search value.

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617278/vba-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-letter

Comment: @Brian - just to avoid confusion with `Range.Find`, that is `WorksheetFunction.Find`. But `InStr` does the same thing and is shorter.

Comment: @BigBen i agree that the duplicate chosen question is useful and helpful, but will explain further in my answer the pitfall (which i have personally fallen into) with `instr()`'s implicit "boolean" response (not really boolean!!!).  that appears tied to not having ">0" after the instr

Comment: @Cyril yes that is good commentary to add to your answer. The dupe target may not be the best, perhaps the 2nd one I posted is better. In any case, both of them use the `>0`.

Comment: @BigBen yes, the second one is solid, as it links to the microsoft documentation.  closed before i could vote lol

Answer (score 0):

Simple splitting of your `instr()`:

```
If InStr(.Cells(i, "M").Value,"Red") > 0 Or InStr(.Cells(i, "M").Value,"Green") > 0 or InStr(.Cells(i, "M").Value,"Blue") > 0 Then
```

From my comment, remember that:

`InStr(,)` accepts one argument for where to look and a second argument for what to find; it outputs long.

---

Improper use of the implicit response of `InStr()`, as you've written, can cause some confusion, so you will want to add the ">0" to your condition.

This will be a true condition:

```
Dim str as string
str = "cat"
If InStr(str, "a") Then
```

The fact that `InStr` returns a value is considered "true" in this case, because of an implicit response... but the next one will be false:

```
Dim str as string
str = "cat"
If InStr(str, "a") And InStr(str, "c") Then
```

The "yes, this has a result" is dropped when moving to the second criteria, meaning not both scenarios are true.  To make the above actually correct, we will add the condition in respect to `InStr()` returning `Long` (not boolean):

```
Dim str as string
str = "cat"
If InStr(str, "a") > 0 And InStr(str, "c") > 0 Then
```

The first `InStr()` returns 2, so true, and the second `InStr()` returns 1, so true...

Comment: Said in another way, `CBool(2)` is `True`, but `CBool(2 And 1)` is `False`.